# Creating a Private Key from a String

Tags: cryptography, elixir, rsa

### Use case

We have an app, where a user puts in a private key into a text box and then we save that. We then want to use that string value to create a private key to be able to sign stuff with it.

### Ruby example

In Ruby this is done with something like this:

```
OpenSSL::Key::RSA.new(string_key_value_here)
```

I know that you can use Erlang's crypto module in Elixir and I thought that the function generate_key/2 could be used here. On further review I don't think that it'll work as the second parameters that it wants for that function are:

```
{ModulusSizeInBits::integer(), PublicExponent::key_value()}
```

Is it possible to do something like this with Elixir / Erlang?

Comment: I think you want http://erlang.org/doc/man/public_key.html#pem_entry_decode-1 with `pki_asn1_type` being `:RSAPrivateKey`.